# How to make a demo game in Unity3d?

Tags: unity-game-engine, demo, trial

I have developed a game in unity3d for pc and mac. I want to publish the game with 30 days trial period.
How do I make it? How do I write into the system registry. What things that I should keep in mind while developing this trial version.
Whenever I search in google, I get trial version of unity3d not about how to make a trial game in unity3d.

Answer (score 1):

The following [article](http://www.kalzumeus.com/2006/09/05/everything-you-need-to-know-about-registration-systems/) has a lot of information, but is pretty long.

**Writing to Registry**
Regarding saving to the registry, only do this if you have a big game and will be writing other values to the registry. If it's just a small indie game, then rather avoid the registry. People don't like it when small indie games write values into their registry, as most developers will never remove that value.

There are 2 ways. You could either make the user "login" to your server every time, also called "Online Validation". This way is more secure, but does require the user to login which is not ideal. You could use the following offline method. Please note that I just thought about this, so there might be small flaws.

**Offline Method**
You could get the current system date and time. Encrypt the date and time and save it to disk. Then every time the game starts up, get the system date and time again and check this "new" time to the date and time you have stored on disk. This check will more be to make sure the user has not modified the system date and time. Obviously overwrite the date and time every time the game is started, but obviously first check the value.

You'll know if the user has modified their time if the "new" date and time you got is not more than the old stored date and time. You could also get the date and time, just before the game exits. Then when the game starts up again, you can make sure that the current date and time is more than the date and time you stored to disk.

Also get the date and time when the game first starts up and save that. As you can then check exactly how many days until their trial runs out.

**What you should keep in mind**
Allow the user to keep their saved game (if they can save). So that when the buy your game, they do not have to start all over again.